# Javascript, drawing a tringle, canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've asked similar question and some good souls tried to help but unfortunately failed.

I was given an assignment by my teacher; I am to collect data from a html form and then print a tringle using the given coordinates. Unfortunately my code is not working and I don't know where the mistake is. Any ideas? It's my first JS program btw so please excuse my imperfection.

Here's the code:
    https://jsfiddle.net/n07engyt/4/

```
    function draw() 
    {
        var welcome_parra = document.getElementById('form');
        var coordinate = document.getElementById('wierzcholekX1')
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
        ctx.beginPath();
        //ctx.moveTo(100,50);
        ctx.moveTo(testX1(), testY1());
        //ctx.lineTo(130, 100);
        ctx.lineTo(testX2(), testY2());
        ctx.lineTo(testX3(), testY3());
        //ctx.lineTo(70, 100);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
        ctx.fill();
    }


    function testX1()
    {
        var welcome_parra = document.getElementById('form');
        var coordinate = document.getElementById('wX1')
        return coordinate.value;
    }

    function testX2()
    {
        var welcome_parra = document.getElementById('form');
        var coordinate = document.getElementById('wX2')
        return coordinate.value;
    }

    function testX3())
    {
        var welcome_parra = document.getElementById('form');
        var coordinate = document.getElementById('wX3')
        return coordinate.value;
    }

    function testY1()
    {
        var welcome_parra = document.getElementById('form');
        var coordinate = document.getElementById('wY1')
        return coordinate.value;
    }

    function testY2()
    {
        var welcome_parra = document.getElementById('form');
        var coordinate = document.getElementById('wY2')
        return coordinate.value;
    }

    function testY3()
    {
        var welcome_parra = document.getElementById('form');
        var coordinate = document.getElementById('wY3')
        return coordinate.value;
    }


    function write_coordinate(){
        draw();
    }
```

I have one more question; is there any better way to do it? Like more elegant not by using separated function for each vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one function to get all the points in an object would be better. If you use forms, you don't have to write `document.getElement..` etc. Here is an example, i believe this would be a neat solution

```js
function getCoordinates() {
  return{
    x1:Number(cordinates.x1.value),
    y1:Number(cordinates.y1.value),
    x2:Number(cordinates.x2.value),
    y2:Number(cordinates.y2.value),
    x3:Number(cordinates.x3.value),
    y3:Number(cordinates.y3.value)
  }
}

function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var p = getCoordinates();
    ctx.fillStyle="#A2322E";
    console.log(p)
    ctx.beginPath();
    
    ctx.moveTo(p["x1"],p["y1"]);
    ctx.lineTo(p["x2"],p["y2"]);
    ctx.lineTo(p["x3"],p["y3"]);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```css
#canvas{
  border:2px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<form name="cordinates">
  <div>
    <input name="x1" type=text placeholder="x1" value="70">
    <input name="y1" type=text placeholder="y1" value="50">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="x2" type=text placeholder="x2" value="100">
    <input name="y2" type=text placeholder="y2" value="75">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="x3" type=text placeholder="x3" value="100">
    <input name="y3" type=text placeholder="y3" value="25">
  </div>
</form>
<button onclick="draw()">draw</button><br/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: This one works perfectly, thank You.

Comment: @ninigi your Welcome. If it is working fine for you, please vote up the answer and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your console and you will see the issue...

Hint: extra `)`

Comment: Yeah, being a beginner in a language... Thank You very much, you saved me a lot of time and effort. But do You happen to know - is there any other way to do it? I'm asking out of curiosity

Comment: You can ask on codereview SE

Comment: Correction @Neal - it's still not drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function draw() 
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    ctx.beginPath();
    //ctx.moveTo(100,50);
    ctx.moveTo(getElementValue('wierzcholekX1'), getElementValue('wierzcholekY1'));
    //ctx.lineTo(130, 100);
    ctx.lineTo(getElementValue('wierzcholekX2'), getElementValue('wierzcholekY2'));
    ctx.lineTo(getElementValue('wierzcholekX3'), getElementValue('wierzcholekY3'));
    //ctx.lineTo(70, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    ctx.fill();
}

function getElementValue(inputID)
{
    return document.getElementById(inputID).value;
}

function write_coordinate()
{
  draw();
}
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/n07engyt/6/)

Comment: Unfortunately not working.

Comment: I tested it using Chrome v.49 and IE10 and it was working. Try JSFiddle link, also the triangle is drown on top of the form, so you have to scroll to top a bit in order to see it

Comment: OK, I'll do it. Thank You @Mohsen Heydari!